# How do you tell if a UIScrollView content overflows

Tags: uiscrollview, swift3, scrollable

I have a UIScroll view with content in it. If that content overflows, making the scroll view scrollable, I'd like to set the bottom of the view to be a certain color. If it does not, I'd like to set it to a different color.

My issue is, I do not know how to detect if a UIScrollView's content overflows and thus is scrollable.

Comment: Check if the scroll view's `contentSize` is bigger than it's `bounds`.

Comment: @paulvs Add as an answer so I can accept. That worked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check if the scroll view's `contentSize` is bigger than its `bounds`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but my scroll view had a content insets set which made the accepted answer slightly off. Here's how to take the content inset into account:

```
if scrollView.contentSize.height + scrollView.contentInset.bottom > scrollView.bounds.size.height {
    // Scroll view is able to scroll.
}
```